# Django button submit not work after using javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

This would be my Registration page. When the script html tag `testscript.js` code is remove or commented out, the *register* button works perfectly fine but when I input the `testscript.js`, the *register* button is kind of disabled. So, I think the problem is the javascript code because that's the only part of the code that blocks the function of the register button.

Here's my source code:

**views.py:**

```
def registration(request):
    form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    print("Working Form")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        print("Form Submitted")
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'activities/index.html', context)
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/CSS/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/CSS/font-awesome/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/CSS/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="../static/Javascript/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="site-header" >
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark index__navbar scrolled">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div>
                <img class="navbar-icon" style="margin-left:15px;" src="../static/Media/avatar.png" alt="dasma-logo">
                <span id="hideHomeTitle" class="brand__name" style="color:#2c5f2dff;">Preschooler Profiling and Monitoring</span>
            </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- Form -->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="homeBody">
        <br>
        <div class="form">
            <div class="form-toggle"></div>
            <div class="form-panel one">
                <div class="form-header">
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="form-content">
                    <form action="">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-remember">
                                <input type="checkbox">Remember Me
                            </label><a class="form-recovery" href="">Forgot Password?</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit">Log In</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-panel two">
                <div class="form-header">
                    <h1>Register Account</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="form-content">
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <label for="">User Type</label>
                            {{ form.user_type }}
                            <br>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="">First Name</label>
                                    {{ form.first_name }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="">Last Name</label>
                                    {{ form.last_name }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Email Address</label>
                            {{ form.email }}
                        </div>
                
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Password</label>
                            {{ form.password1 }}
                        </div>
                
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Confirm Password</label>
                            {{ form.password2 }}
                        </div>
                
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit">Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/Javascript/testscript.js"></script>
</html>
```

**testscript.js:**

```
$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    var $nav = $(".fixed-top");
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var panelOne = $('.form-panel.two').height(),
      panelTwo = $('.form-panel.two')[0].scrollHeight;
  
    $('.form-panel.two').not('.form-panel.two.active').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  
      $('.form-toggle').addClass('visible');
      $('.form-panel.one').addClass('hidden');
      $('.form-panel.two').addClass('active');
      $('.form').animate({
        'height': panelTwo
      }, 200);
    });
  
    $('.form-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).removeClass('visible');
      $('.form-panel.one').removeClass('hidden');
      $('.form-panel.two').removeClass('active');
      $('.form').animate({
        'height': panelOne
      }, 200);
    });
  });
```

**styles.css:**

```
/* Login Form */
  .overlay, .form-panel.one:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .form {
    z-index: 15;
    position: relative;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 100px auto 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .form-toggle {
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    right: 60px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: translate(0, -25%) scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  .form-toggle:before, .form-toggle:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 4px;
    background: rgb(33, 146, 71);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  .form-toggle:before {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  }
  .form-toggle:after {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .form-toggle.visible {
    transform: translate(0, -25%) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .form-group{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
  }
  .form-group:last-child {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .form-group label ,.input-group label{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  }
  .two .form-group label ,.input-group label{
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }

  .form-group input {
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: inherit;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
  }
  .form-group input:focus {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
  .two .form-group input {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .two .form-group input:focus  {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .form-group button {
    outline: none;
    background: rgb(33, 146, 71);
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: inherit;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .two .form-group button{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: rgb(33, 146, 71);
  }
  .form-group .form-remember {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    text-transform: none;
  }
  .form-group .form-remember input[type=checkbox] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  }
  .form-group .form-recovery {
    color: rgb(33, 146, 71);
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .form-panel {
    padding: 60px calc(5% + 60px) 60px 60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .form-panel.one:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
  }
  .form-panel.one.hidden:before {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .form-panel.two {
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 95%;
    background: rgb(33, 146, 71);
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 60px calc(10% + 60px) 60px 60px;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .form-panel.two:before, .form-panel.two:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 1.5%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    height: 30px;
    width: 2px;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
  }
  .form-panel.two:after {
    left: 3%;
  }
  .form-panel.two:hover {
    left: 93%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  .form-panel.two:hover:before, .form-panel.two:hover:after {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .form-panel.two.active {
    left: 10%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    cursor: default;
  }
  .form-panel.two.active:before, .form-panel.two.active:after {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .form-header {
    margin: 0 0 40px;
  }
  .form-header h1 {
    padding: 4px 0;
    color: rgb(33, 146, 71);
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .two .form-header h1 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 40;
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
```

I know it's too long but I hope someone would have a solution for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Django button which is not working after using javascript code is because , I feel like the div with form-panel is been used in the Js code whereas If you see the button is also under the same tag(form-panel). Try by removing the button div and place it outside the main div.
I hope it help. Best of luck